CPU Register concept sketch using TikZ
I want to draw a CPU register set as shown at my hand-made concept draw:

My LaTeX source so far is:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xstring}

\StrLen{Register Rx}[\RegStrLen]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  font=\sffamily
]
\matrix[%draw,
  row 1/.style={nodes={text height=0},font=\scriptsize},draw=none,
  column 1/.style={nodes={draw}},
  column 2/.style={nodes={draw,minimum width=\RegStrLen}},
  column 3/.style={nodes={draw,minimum width=\RegStrLen}}
  ]
  {
  %
  \node[anchor=east] {31}; & & \node[anchor=west] {0}; \\
  & \node {R0}; \\
  & \node {R1}; \\
  & \node {R2}; \\
  & \node {R3}; \\
  & \node {R4}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

It fails to get the right border drawn around the R(egister)-labeled columns, where the first column doesn't have it. The MSB und LSB (31 und 0) shall be aligned to the left, resp. right side.
Getting curly braces - I also failed :( As well as to draw the so-called shadow-registers A and B, the text around  ...
Not the AI help of CoCalc, the VisualTikZ nor PGF Manual gave me a hint how to accomplish my task/wish. I also searched at StackExchange for those solution hints without results.
At least the fontsize of the first column looks promising :-)
So, what could be a solution using TikZ?

Welcome! Sorry, but I'm not following an obscure link posted by a stranger. You can upload an image into your question (if the licence permits you to do so) or you can try to describe what specifically you're stuck on in words. I'm guessing that the fit library and likely the matrix library may be helpful. AI produces terrible LaTeX code so far as I know and it is probably even worse for PGF/TikZ.

I can understand that, but I'm so new that I'm not allowed to upload pictures yet :(

I think they won't render them, but if you add them somebody else can then make them visible. But I apologise: I'd forgotten about that restriction.

Something like this?


You should include your sketch to question. After while given link may become death ...
Sorry, but some of your hand writing text is unreadable to me, so you need to insert correct text yourself.
Also color of cells is not visible well, consequently in picture they may be wrongly interpreted-

As starting point:
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,     
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                }


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 0mm and 7mm,
   start chain = A going below,
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1,
              #2},% for mirroring of brace
        thick,
        pen colour={#3}
        },
 N/.style = {draw, fill=#1, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=21mm, outer sep=0pt,
             text opacity=1, align=center},
 N/.default = gray!30,
                            ]
\begin{scope}[nodes=on chain]
\foreach \i in {0, 1,...,4} 
{\ifnum\i<4
\node[N] {R\i}; 
 \else
\node[N=white] {R\i};
 \fi
}
\end{scope}
\node[above] at (A-1.north west) {31};
\node[above] at (A-1.north east) {1};
%
\node (a) [N, fill opacity=0.5, above right=of A-4.east,
           label=right:text]     {A};
\node (b) [N, fill opacity=0.5, right=3mm of A-4]  {B};
\node[right=of b]  {text};
    \draw[densely dashed]   (A-4.north east) -- (a.north west)
                            (A-4.south east) -- (b.south west);
\node (n1)  [above=3mm] at (A-1.north)  {text};
\node (n3)              at (n1 -| a)    {text};
%
\draw[BC=1/ /red]  (A-1.north east) -- node[right=3mm] {text} (A-3.south east);
%
\draw[BC=1/mirror/red]  (A-1.north west) -- node[left=3mm] {Low}    (A-2.south west);
\draw[BC=1/mirror/red]  (A-3.north west) -- node[left=3mm] {Hight}  (A-4.south west);
\node[left=3mm of A-5] {Foo};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Nice - I always forget about calligraphy!

@cfr, thank you very much!

That's about what I had in mind. Thank you very much! (1) How can I increase the space between the register blocks and the curly brackets, (2) move block with text "A" up a little to prevent the text/font from being hidden (readability) and still maintain the overlap for meaning and (3) align the two associated texts "text" left below each other? I'm looking forward to a steep learning curve with TikZ :-)

@olStckEx, increase parameter #1 in BC style, for example to 2mm. Text in blocks A and B are well visible, hover you can move A s follows: \node (a) [N, fill opacity=0.5, above right= 3mm and 7mm of A-4.east,. I suggest you to read tikz package. For star it will be sufficient to read first tutorial in third part "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm".
label=right:text]     {A};

The function \StrLen in the xstring package does not measure the length of a string. It counts the number of characters!
To measure the length of a character string, use the macro  \settowidth
\newlength{\RegStrLen}
\settowidth{\RegStrLen}{Register Rx}

I've simplified your code by using a single-column matrix and placed the nodes using the usual Tikz parameters. If you have any questions, I'll answer them.
As for braces, I've taken the parameters from Zarko's answer.
Complete code:
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,positioning,patterns}
\newlength{\RegStrLen}
\settowidth{\RegStrLen}{Register Rx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,decoration={calligraphic brace,raise=3pt, pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,post=moveto, post length=1pt,amplitude=3pt},
every node/.style={minimum height=7mm}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw,minimum width=\RegStrLen,minimum height=7mm,
fill=purple!30},
row 5/.style={nodes={fill=yellow!30}}
](m)
  {
   R0  \\
   R1  \\
   R2  \\
   R3  \\
   R4  \\
  };
  \node[above =5mm of m-1-1](n){Name};
  \node[right =22mm of n](f){Function};
  \node[anchor=south west,inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=2pt] at (m-1-1.north west){31};
  \node[anchor=south east,inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=2pt] at (m-1-1.north east){1};
\draw[decorate](m-2-1.south west)--node[anchor=east,xshift=-5pt]{Low}(m-1-1.north west);
\draw[decorate](m-4-1.south west)--node[anchor=east,xshift=-5pt]{High}(m-3-1.north west);
\node[left=0mm of m-5-1,anchor=east,xshift=-5pt]{Foo};

\draw[decorate](m-1-1.north east)--node[anchor=west,xshift=5pt]{General}(m-3-1.south east);
\node[draw,text width=\RegStrLen,right= 2cm of m-3-1,align=center,text depth=5pt,pattern={crosshatch},pattern color=brown!50](b){B};
\draw(m-4-1.north east)--(b.north west);

\node[right=5pt of b](x){XPtv};
\node[draw,text width=\RegStrLen,below left = 4pt and 10pt of b.east,align=center,fill=brown!50,fill opacity=.5,text opacity=1](a){A};
\node[below =0pt of x]{YPtv};
\draw(m-5-1.north east)--(a.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you, you gave me the hint to align the descriptions of XPtr and YPtr!

If you think my answer is useful, why don't you upvote for it?

Sorry, done. I'm new here.

Thanks. If you feel that one of the two answers is the most useful to you, you must accept it, otherwise the system will bring up this question indefinitely.
